# Tel field validation in html to allow digits and text but not @

Tags: javascript, html, regex

This code is only digit allowed – Preference should be to allow to enter dash and/or brackets even text such as ext. but not an email address.

Can you please help me to edit this code? Very appreciated.

```
  <input type="text" maxlength="40" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" required name="phone" id="phonecontactselection">
```

Comment: You basically you should allow whatever character, but not @, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) and a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and list your characters that you would allow to match.

In this case match one of `[`, `]`, a character `a-z`, dot or a hyphen:

```
[\][a-z.-]
```

```html
<input 
 type="text" 
 maxlength="40" 
 onkeypress="return /[\][a-z.-]/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.which || event.keyCode));"   
 required 
 name="phone" 
 id="phonecontactselection"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a function to check only for `@` character to avoid it, so:

```
function avoidEmailPartCharacter(event) {
  const code = event.keyCode || event.which;
  if (code === 64) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

then you pass the function to the input `keypress` handler, like so:

```
<input type="type" keypress={avoidEmailPartCharacter(this)} />
```

it should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable to move such kind of logic of out template, into a dedicated function, however, **in case you really have to make it inline**, it's possible to match input character against a regex as follows:

```html
<input type="text"
       maxLength="40"
       onkeypress="return !!String.fromCharCode(event.which || event.charCode).match(/[\dext\[\]\-]/)"
       required
       name="phone"
       id="phonecontactselection"
>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. You're the best

Comment: @Tat My pleasure!